# Library using libclang: linker reporting undefined reference to method

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, clang

as a project of my own, I'm writing a refactoring library (so it can by used by other applications) using libclang for code analysis.
The problem is when i try to compile my program to a static library everything is okey, but when i try to link my library (using some clang code) with some demo application (just main function calling my code) the linker is reporting:

```
./librefactor.a(renamer.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x60): undefined reference to 'clang::ASTConsumer::HandleInterestingDecl(clang::DeclGroupRef)'
./librefactor.a(renamer.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x80): undefined reference to `clang::ASTConsumer::HandleTopLevelDeclInObjCContainer(clang::DeclGroupRef)'
./librefactor.a(renamer.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x88): undefined reference to `clang::ASTConsumer::HandleImplicitImportDecl(clang::ImportDecl*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is a makefile I build my library with: [library makefile](http://pastebin.com/CZWyFkY5)

Here is a makefile I build an example with: [library example](http://pastebin.com/d2Z7YS55)

I commented out some parts of the code to make the error as short as possible but they are some similiar errors (undefined reference) from other part of clang i use in my project.

Problem is I don't understand why linker can't find definitions of these functions/methods. They are not pure virtual in base class so I don't need to defined them. As I see it the linker is trying to find the definition of these in my part of the code istead in clang binaries. Could somebody please explain me where I'm wrong here and explain/repair it?